# Home partition in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bios

If I partition my home drive in recovery mode (ubuntu 14.04), will my os get formated?

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not get formated.

Your new partition will be created by free space of your system.

So your system partition will be shrinked and you will get a new empty disk volume.

Then you can use it like a storage drive or to install another OS to dual boot...  :)

Comment: see i have 500GB of hardisk, and the whole thing is my home drive 500GB, now how will i partition or resize that without formating it or delete it?

Comment: You have to boot from a live CD or USB and use **gparted** to resize your partition.